# Websites for free feedback on stories?

Tags: editing, short-story, websites, criticism, feedback

Are there any websites or anything similar where we can get feedback from online readers (without paying for a membership or anything of the sort) for stories and other writings that are not quite finished, but are rather WIPs?

As I understand, Writing.StackExchange does not encourage questions asking for (general) feedback on given excerpts, so where can I go to get such feedback?

Comment: you might try Critique Circle http://www.critiquecircle.com/. While I've never used the service, other people here have praised it.

Comment: Same situation as Lauren Ipsum, I've not tried it but there is a show your work part of the Absolute Write forums where one can get feedback (free). YMMV, lots of people love the site, quite a few have had issues.

Comment: Sorry I should charity, the issues people had are from disagreements on the forums, not in terms of bad feedback (wasn't clear before)

Answer (score 2):

[Critique Circle](http://www.critiquecircle.com/newmembersinfo.asp) is great. I highly recommend it. It's "free" but requires to critique the work of others to earn the points needed to submit work. The interface is really ugly, but the feedback is great.

[Scribophile](http://www.scribophile.com/) is a similar site, and while its inexpensive premium accounts are nice, the free version is fine. Its looks are a bit more polished. You do have to have picked you pen name first.

Answer (score 0):

Critique Circle has been mentioned so I'll try to suggest a few new ideas. First of all, there is [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/home) and its forum. There are a lot of good editors and writers there, but it requires some work to find them as there are even more users you'll prefer not to meet.

Also, Twitter- There are different tags which you can use to find people interested in writing, editing, critiquing, etcetera. Just try to make conversations with them introducing yourself and asking for the help you need.

And lastly, [NaNoWriMo](http://nanowrimo.org/)- a large online meeting of writers. Even if you don't agree with the challenge itself, there are many experienced writers there who can gladly help you. Just try it out.

Good luck with your writing :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called Prose that's based around sharing your work and chatting about it with fellow writers. I haven't posted much as of yet but it seems like friendly, pressure free community. And they make it crystal clear that you retain the copyright and ownership of your work. That's important because there are sites where that's not the case and by uploading something you're basically saying "Do whatever you want with it."
I'd also second NaNoWriMo. Very supportive and encouraging community, especially in November.

Answer (score 0):

I started using http://www.legendfire.com/ and I like it. It is entirely free and simple in a good way. It is a relatively small community but you don't really need a whole lot of people if the people that are present are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[YoungWritersSociety](https://www.youngwriterssociety.com/index.php) is a great place. It's got a really active community, but it's geared toward younger and less experienced writers - but it still works for the better, elder writers, too.